# Is it possible to transfer the contents of a whole directory using the built in Ruby Net::FTP class?

Tags: ruby, file, io, ftp, transfer

I'm building an application in Ruby that has a command which will transfer the contents of a certain directory to a remote FTP server. I know that the way to transfer a single file via ftp in Ruby is:

```
file = File.open('file.txt')
    Net::FTP.open(ftp_server, username, password) { |ftp|
    ftp.putbinaryfile(file)
}
```

I just don't know how to transfer the contents of a directory via the build in FTP class. If somebody could give me an example of how to do this, or knows of a Ruby library that can do this it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, get all files and subdirectories in your directory:

```
entries = Dir.glob('my_dir/**/*').sort
```

(`sort` is required to ensure that every directory goes before its files)

Now you can upload all files and create all subdirectories:

```
Net::FTP.open(ftp_server, username, password) do |ftp|
  entries.each do |name|
    if File::directory? name
      ftp.mkdir name
    else
      File.open(name) { |file| ftp.putbinaryfile(file, name) }
    end
  end
end
```

I had no time to test this, so I could miss something.

Comment: Yes this is the way it would have to be done as when you use a FTP client to transfer directories it is doing mkdir.. put put put under the hood.